# How do I return an iterator?

Tags: multi-index

I have a multi-index defined such that I can do:

```
<type?> test() {
    myTable t(_self, _self.value);
    auto r = t.find(...);
    return r;
}
```

but how do I return the iterator?  what is the type I need to declare for my method?

according to https://eosio.github.io/eosio.cdt/1.6.0/group__multiindex.html#function-find the return type is `const_iterator` but the compiler complains that no type of that name exists, and the documentation says nothing of where I might find the type

help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type is your table type as a namespace for the `const_iterator`, like this: `myTable::const_iterator`.

However, it is probably best to just return type `auto`. That way you can't go wrong.

Comment: I did try the `eosio` namespace as you recommended but that did not work.  `auto` was the right answer but it I could not return r.  I needed to return `&*r`

Comment: What was the error message when you tried to just return `r`?

Comment: @ekkis I updated my answer for the case where you don't want to use auto

Comment: I did try `myTable::` but the compiler kept complaining the symbol didn't exist.  I think I needed to scope it: `token::myTable::const_iterator`

Answer (score 2):

You can return auto. Your code example would then look like this:

```
// attention, undefined behaviour
auto test() {
    myTable t{_self, _self.value};
    return t.find(...);
}
```

In your code example, however, the variable t is stack allocated and goes out of scope at the end of the function. That results in undefined behaviour since you are now returning an iterator which points to an object whose memory has been deallocated.

If you still really want to do it, you need to allocate on the heap. Since inside a smart contract, we don't need to take care of cleanup up memory, probably the simplest way of doing it would be like this:

```
auto test() {
    auto *t = new myTable{_self, _self.value};
    return t->find(...);
}
```